# Finding a point on the unit circle that achieves this equality

Tags: geometry

> Let $n>0$ and $A_1,\ldots A_n$ be points on the unit 2D circle. Prove there is  some $B$ on the unit circle such that $||A_1B||\cdot||A_2B||\ldots\cdot||A_nB||=1$
>
> ( $||A_iB||$ is the euclidean distance in the 2D plane between $A_i$ and $B$.)

I was tasked with this problem, except geometry is not really my thing. I don't really have a clue about what should be done. Induction looks pointless, so I'd go for an analytic solution: given angles $a_1,\ldots a_n$, it boils down to finding $b$ such that $$\prod_{k=1}^n((\cos(a_k)-\cos(b))^2+(\sin(a_k)-\sin(b))^2)=1$$

that is $$\prod_{k=1}^n(2-2(\cos(a_k)\cos(b)+\sin(a_k)\sin(b))=1$$

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n(1-\cos(a_k-b))=\frac{1}{2^n} $$

Thus it remains to find some $b$ that satisfies the last equation (I might actually post this as another question).

**EDIT**: This approach yields a solution indeed: see [Proving the existence of $b$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^n(1-\cos(a_k-b))=\frac{1}{2^n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284531/proving-the-existence-of-b-such-that-prod-k-1n1-cosa-k-b-frac12)

Comment: Is $\|A_1 B\|$ the distance of $A_1$ and $B$?

Comment: @LeBtz It's the euclidean distance in the 2D plane between $A_1$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We identify $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$.

Let $f(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n (z-A_k)$.
Then, using Cauchy integral formula, we have

$\displaystyle f(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S^1} \frac{f(z)}{z} dz$.

It follows that 
$$1 = |f(0)| = \left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{S^1}\frac{f(z)}{z}dz\right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{S^1}\left|\frac{f(z)}{z}\right||dz| \leq \sup\limits_{z\in S^1} \left| \frac{f(z)}{z} \right| = \sup\limits_{z\in S^1} |f(z)|$$

Because of continuity of $|f|$ we have $w\in S^1$ with $|f(w)| = \sup\limits_{z\in S^1} |f(z)| \geq 1$. Applying intermediate value theorem and $|f(A_1)| = 0$, we get $B\in S^1$ with $|f(B)| = 1$ satisfying the condition.

Comment: Is there a "real" way to this ? I never had any exposure to complex analysis.

Comment: Will be harder. I'll think about it.