# Proving the existence of $b$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^n(1-\cos(a_k-b))=\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, optimization

> Let $n>0$ and $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in \mathbb R$. Prove there is some $b$ such that $\prod_{k=1}^n(1-\cos(a_k-b))=\frac{1}{2^n}$

This is motivated by this question [Finding a point on the unit circle that achieves this equality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283528/finding-a-point-on-the-unit-circle-that-achieves-this-equality)

Numerical trials suggest it is true indeed, and that for any choice of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, $b\to \prod_{k=1}^n(1-\cos(a_k-b))$ achieves a maximum quite greater that $\frac{1}{2^n}$.

**EDIT**: It may be worth noting that: $$\prod_{k=1}^n(1-\cos(a_k-b))=2^n\prod_{k=1}^n\sin^2(\frac{a_k-b}{2})$$

I attempted induction on $n$, to no avail.

Comment: Isn't that question already answered?

Comment: Well the other question is indeed answered (altough I can't understand the solution). But I believe the approach I suggested should be a question per se, since it has quite nothing to do with the original problem.

Comment: Well, since you proved that finding a solution to that problem is equivalent to finding a $b$ that satisfies this relation. And he proved that the problem does have a solution. So such a $b$ must exist. (otherwise, there would be no solutions.

Comment: I guess that we must take the product as a function of $b$, then use mean value property...

Comment: @k1.M Yes, that's the approach I've been pondering on for a day, without success...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$F(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1-\cos(a_i-x)\right)$$
for any $a_i$. Now, noticing that $F(x)\ge0$ for all $x$, we look at
$$\ln F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(1-\cos(a_i-x)\right)$$
and compute the average over all $x$:
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln F(x)\,dx
=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos(a_i-x)\right)\,dx.
$$
However, the value of the last integral does not depend on $a_i$ as we have
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos(a_i-x)\right)\,dx
=\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos u\right)\,du
=-2\pi\ln 2,
$$
resulting in
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\ln F(x)\,dx=-n\ln 2.
$$
Now, since the average is $-n\ln 2$ and $F(x)$ is not constant, there must be some value of $x$ for which $\ln F(x)>-n\ln 2$, which makes $F(x)>1/2^n$.

---

On a side node, if the $a_i$ are evenly spread using $a_i=2\pi i/n$, we get $F(x)=2^{1-n}(1-\cos(nx))$ which has maximum $2^{2-n}$: i.e., four times what we have proven.

A natural follow-up question is if the maximum of $F(x)$ will always be $2^{2-n}$ or higher?

Comment: Nicely done. I couldn't have imagined integrating would solve the problem.

Comment: One last question: how did you compute $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos u\right)\,du$ ? A CAS returns $-2\pi \ln(2)$ indeed, but I'm wondering how to do it with pen and paper.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: I was lazy and plugged it into Maple, according to which the indefinite integral is expressed in terms of the dilog function. Alternatives I can think of is complex analysis which is often good for some special definite integrals, and power expansion of the $\ln$ function and then summing the integrated terms, neither of which is completely straight forward.

Comment: One has $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos u\right)\,du=2\pi\ln(2)+4\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(v))dv$, but $\int_0^{\pi}\ln(\sin(v))dv=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(v))dv:=2I$. Setting $J=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin(v))dv$, one has $I=J$ and $I+J=I-\pi/2\ln(2)$, which yields the expected value of $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln\left(1-\cos u\right)\,du$.